# SWIG carrays/classes prematurely destroyed in Python

Tags: python, c++, swig

I'm trying to work with a fairly common structure I think in C/C++, something along the lines:

```
// data.hpp
class Element {
  public:  
    int value;
    ~Element() { std::cout << "In node destructor" << std::endl; }
};

class Row {
  public: 
    Row(Element *elements) {/*initialize elements, assign ptrs*/}; 
    std::vector<Element *> elements;
};

class Dataset {
  public:  
    Dataset(Row *rows) {/*initialize rows, assign ptrs*/};
    std::vector<Row *> rows;
};
```

Storing pointers because this is actually used both on the CPU and GPU (CUDA) and I just want to store the pointer so each device can figure out the actual position of the object by itself.

My SWIG mapping is pretty basic:

```
/* File : data.i */
%{
#include "data.hpp"
%}

%include carrays.i
%include "data.hpp"

%array_class(Node, NodeArray)
%array_class(Row, RowArray)
```

Now I need to convert Python/Numpy array into and array of rows so I can pass them to the `Dataset` constructor. Thought something like this might work:

```
def array_to_rows(X):
    nr_rows = np.shape(X)[0]
    c_row_arr = example.RowArray(nr_nodes)
    for r in range(nr_rows):
        nr_nodes = len(X[r])
        c_node_arr = example.NodeArray(nr_nodes)
        for n in range(nr_nodes):
            node = example.Node()
            node.value = int(X[r][n])
            c_node_arr[n] = node // <-- after this line node's destructor is called
        c_row_arr[r] = example.Row(node_arr) // <-- after this line row's destructor is called and destructor for each Node in c_node_arr
    return c_row_arr
```

Sample call:

```
import example as example
X = [
     [1],
     [2,3],
     [4,5,6]
     ]
rows = array_to_rows(X)
```

The issue is, at the end of each loop in Python, the destructors for both `Node` and `Row` are called. So even though I do `c_node_arr[n] = node` this assignment doesn't make Python hold on to `node` but deletes it...

I'm assuming this is because SWIG arrays are working with pointers and if I do `c_node_arr[n] = node` it will just set the pointer to `node`, which then will get released by Python at the end of the loop (and the C++ destructor will be called) and the `c_node_arr` will be left hanging with a pointer to a memory location which already got freed.

Is there any workaround? Is my approach just plain bad and I should rethink it (how?).

@Edit:

For now the only workaround I see is:

1) to hold all instances of `RowArray` and `NodeArray` also in a Python list and release them when I'm done

2) change the assignments to `RowArray` and `NodeArray` from `=` to `__setitem(idx, value)`

Answer (score 0):

I think what's happening is SWIG is triggering many copies of your C++ objects. I don't think it is leaving any dangling pointers.

From http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Library.html, `%array_class(type,name)` is:

```
struct name {
  ...
  void setitem(int index, type value);  // Set item
}
```

I assume that's what happens at `c_node_arr[n] = node`.

So you actually have:

1. [Python] `c_node_arr.__setitem__(n, node)`: Pass `node` into SWIG.
2. [SWIG] Extract the underlying `Node*`.
3. [SWIG] Call `name::setitem(..., *node)`.
4. [C++] As part of parameter passing, construct a new `Node` object as a copy of the argument (as if `Node new_node = node;`). Try to write a copy constructor for Element, I think you will see a call here.
5. [C++] Store it in some internal array of `struct name`. I guess this second copy is somehow elided.
6. ... later ... [Python] Decides to delete the original `node` object. This is where you see the destructor running. Internally, `NodeArray` points to (and owns) a copy of the original node.

If `Element`, `Row` can be made copyable (with default or custom copy constructors), then everything is fine.